# NSArray is not convertible to Array<Row>

Tags: swift

Upon revisiting some code that seemed to work with Xcode6 , I noticed that I am getting a "`NSArray is not convertible to Array<Row>' to type 'NSArray'`" error for this line:

```
var array  = (data as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchpredicte!) as? [AnyObject]
```

here is code

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    data1.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    var searchpredicte = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", serchcontroller.searchBar.text)

    var array  = (data as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchpredicte!) as? [AnyObject]
    // error above 1 line

    data1 = array as Array<Row>

    self.table.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Your code comment suggests the error is on the `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` line, but your subject line suggests that the error is the following line of code. Which is it? I find it hard to imagine that the first line would cause a problem, but I can easily imagine that the latter would be a problem (if the array returned by `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` returned something other than an array of `Row` objects).

Comment: bro when i write data as NSArray then error occur

Comment: i want to define data = Array<Row>

Comment: Can you please double check the precise text of the error message? That doesn't seem like it's quite right. (And while I assume you believe it to be a collegial term, I'd rather not be called "bro". lol.)